# Strange account activity - how to investigate

Tags: authentication, passwords, email

Today I have observed very strange scenario which appears to be attempts to hack an account. So first, let me tell the pre-story:

I have started to receive 2-factor authentication SMS messages from Google/Microsoft/Facebook/Instagram with similar content (like use 1234 to verify your account, and similar). What is more interesting - I use different passwords for each service... I don't believe these passwords were 'p0wned'. Anyway, it was time to first fix the issue and then investigate how this happened. I have reinstalled windows on my PC from trusty source (by verifying ISO checksum before install) and then changed the passwords. I have also checked log in activity - not much unusual (except, probably login attempts from China, but these failed on incorrect password).

So now I am having hard times to understand the way I was attacked and how attack has been progressed. And this is something that I am still confused. And this is I would like to ask the community:

1. Have you observed such a behavior? Could it be that this is just attempt to guess password (or forgot password link)?
2. Could you suggest any other ways to cross-check any illegal activity? No new messages/posts or other traces found..

Any advice on attack surface and ways to mitigate would be welcomed.

Comment: To start, you could check https://haveibeenpwned.com as a sanity check.

Comment: Thanks for advice, fortunately or not... I am not pwned, meaning leakage has happened in some other way...